# Python function argument of predicate type a=b

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Pardon my Python skill or the lack of it. I saw some methods calls of the form

```
auth_req = urllib2.Request(auth_uri, data=authreq_data)
```

If I put in just `authreq_data` I get an error. What is the correct technical definition for this type of method argument? Is it a boolean/predicate type?

Answer (score 7):

They're called [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

You can use them without specifying the keyword, so long as you also pass all the arguments before them.

The signature of [urrlib2.Request](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) is

```
urllib2.Request(url[, data][, headers][, origin_req_host][, unverifiable])
```

So as long as you specify the url, `auth_uri` in this case, you should be able to pass `authreq_data` without specifying that it is the `data` argument.

```
auth_req = urllib2.Request(auth_uri, authreq_data)
```

Python 3 has also added a syntax for specifying [keyword only arguments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Answer (score 0):

It's a [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).